# Laravel middleware doesn't redirect url with locale code

Tags: php, laravel, localization, laravel-5.8, laravel-middleware

I changed the URL structure of laravel 5.8 from `domain.com/about` to `domain.com/[locale]/about`.
 I want redirect my all visitors from old url `domain.com/about` to new url `domain.com/[locale]/about` with their language code. My LanguageMiddleware detects and set locale but doesn't redirect to new url and falls to 404 page.

When I see 404 error page my LanguageMiddleware doesn't show returns of `request()->segment(1)` or `request()->path()`

How do I most accurately redirect old URLs to the new structure?

routes/web.php - for set locale prefix to all urls.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => app()->getLocale()], function () {
    ...
});
```

LanguageMiddleware.php - Detect and set language after redirect new urls with locale

```
class LanguageMiddleware
{
    protected $languages = ['en', 'tr', 'ru', 'fr', 'de'];

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // Locale detect and set (working)
        if (!session()->has('locale')) {
            session()->put('locale', request()->getPreferredLanguage($this->languages));
        }
        app()->setLocale(session()->get('locale'));


        // redirect from domain.com/about to domain.com/[locale]/about (doesn't work and falls 404 page with old url)
        $params = explode('/', request()->path());
        $language = $params[0];
        if (!in_array($language, $this->languages)) {
            return redirect(app()->getLocale().'/'.request()->path(), 301);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello Please add this middleware into `app/Http/Kernel.php`.

`protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'language' => \App\Http\Middleware\LanguageMiddleware::class,
];`

And also add middleware into your route group, show below example for this :

`Route::post('login', 'Api\Auth\ApiLoginController@login')->middleware('language');`

For more details: [How to add locale into url](https://laraveldaily.com/multi-language-routes-and-locales-with-auth/)

Comment: Good way, but I can create url, I can't redirect from old url to new